# Is Windows 10 SDK required for Windows development with C++ in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am installing Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition and desktop dev with C++, but I don't have much space so I excluded the Windows 10 SDK from the optional features.

My question is, is it highly necessarily to install the Windows 10 SDK in order to be able to develop windows apps?

Comment: I'm sure it's told in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/system-requirements)

Comment: Allow me two questions? Have you installed VS2022 on a calculator that you have no space? And are you going directly or through the library side - calls to WinApi functions?

Comment: Depends on what you want to develop.   The windows SDK is necessary if you intend to develop windows applications (with GUI, low-level graphics, windows filesystem specific I/O, tweaking registry settings, developing windows services or device drivers, etc etc).   It is not necessary if you limit yourself to what is possible with standard C++ (console-only output, using the C++ standard library, etc).   If you don't know, but have in mind "I just want my applications to have a windows interface" then you need the windows SDK.

Comment: Well, technically, you don't *need* the SDK. The most important pieces it offers you - API declarations, import libraries, etc, *can* be coded/obtained manually on an as-needed basis. The SDK simply provides the hard work already done for you. But it does offer access to a LOT of things out of the box.

Comment: Visual studio eats a lot of space for each project/solution. Temporary files tend to take several GB. So if you don't have space for SDK then... I doubt you can even use it. Maybe there's a low-space mode? I didn't check it.

Comment: The build dependencies for C standard library, i.e. header files and build libraries, became part of Windows SDK a few years back - even basic C programming requires the SDK, if you decide to use the Microsoft tool chain. This is different from the C runtime, provided as relatively smaller packages in the form of "redistributables".